# In Geoserver, how to give different colors of features within a single shapefile based on the value of a field?

Tags: geoserver

In arcgis, this can be easily done by using the Symbology tab in the properties.I need to achieve a similar effect in Geoserver. How can I do it?

Comment: Have you looked at using SLD's?

Comment: I get an impression that it will do by skimming SLD the documents. I hope that someone with experiences can confirm my guess.

Comment: Yes, SLD can be used for this purpose. See this example: http://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/user/styling/sld-cookbook/polygons.html#attribute-based-polygon

Comment: ...and you can use QGIS to create a style and then save it as an SLD file which you can upload to GeoServer, if you want to save yourself some typing.

Comment: @MappaGnosis  thanks. do you have a url for a tutorial/example on how to create a style in QGIS?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See the [User Guide](http://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/index.html) - especially the section on [styling](http://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/styling/index.html)